# How to properly format my panel data in R?

Tags: r, panel, reshape, melt

I know that similar questions exist but I have tried everything from melt to reshape to Stacked, etc. and nothing is getting me even close.

My data currently looks like this:

```
ID Treatment Round_1_Decision1 Round_1_Decision2 Round_2_Decision1 Round_2_Decision2
1      2            1                0                0                1
2      1            0                0                1                1
```

I need it to instead look like this:

```
ID Treatment Round Decision1 Decision2
1      2       1       1         0
1      2       2       0         1
2      1       1       0         0
2      1       2       1         1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `pivot_longer` - main things to consider is the `names_to` and `names_pattern`.  Here, we need 'Round' column that should generate the values as the suffix of 'Round' in column name and the other column as the value of the column (`.value`).  In the `names_pattern`, capture the column names substring as a group with capture group (`(...)`) i.e. -`\\w+` - should match the 'Round', followed by the `_`, then capture the digits(`(\\d+)`), then the underscore (`_`) followed by the next capture group (`(.*`)) that includes the rest of the characters for the `.value` part

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = starts_with("Round"),
     names_to = c("Round", ".value"), names_pattern = "\\w+_(\\d+)_(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
     ID Treatment Round Decision1 Decision2
  <int>     <int> <chr>     <int>     <int>
1     1         2 1             1         0
2     1         2 2             0         1
3     2         1 1             0         0
4     2         1 2             1         1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Treatment = 2:1, Round_1_Decision1 = 1:0, 
    Round_1_Decision2 = c(0L, 0L), 
Round_2_Decision1 = 0:1, Round_2_Decision2 = c(1L, 
    1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. This almost works perfectly but I have 20 rounds and this code is only reporting the second number (e.g. for Round 17 it's just showing "7" in the Round column). How would I fix that?

Comment: @CameronKormylo can you change the code to `names_pattern = "\\w+(\\d+)_(.*)")`.  Does it have space between Round and 17?  In the data showed, it didn't show any space i.e. Round17.  If that is the case, the code should work without any modificiation i.e. without any space between Round and 17

Comment: Apologies, the true naming convention is Round_17_Decision1

Comment: @CameronKormylo in that case chanage the pattern to `"\\w+_(\\d+)_(.*)"`

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. I will accept this answer once it allows me. It says I have to wait 3 more minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach without using `names_pattern` argument

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=-c(ID, Treatment),
    names_to = "Round",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Decision = str_sub(Round, -9, -1),
         Round = parse_number(Round)
         ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Decision,
    values_from = value
  )
```

```
     ID Treatment Round Decision1 Decision2
  <int>     <int> <dbl>     <int>     <int>
1     1         2     1         1         0
2     1         2     2         0         1
3     2         1     1         0         0
4     2         1     2         1         1
```